# Include parameters in posgresql assert message

Tags: sql, postgresql, assert

Is there a way to include parameters in PostgreSQL ASSERT messages.

Example:

```
do $$ 
declare
    c integer;
begin
    c := (select count(*) from pg_database);
    assert c = 7, 'not 7!';
    assert c = 8, 'not 8!';
    assert c = 5, ('% not 5!' , c);
end;$$;
```

This works:

```
assert c = 8, 'not 8!';
```

This assert:

```
assert c = 5, ('% not 5!' , c);
```

show an error message as it should:

```
SQL Error [P0004]: ERROR: ("% not 5!",7)
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at ASSERT
ERROR: ("% not 5!",7)
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at ASSERT
ERROR: ("% not 5!",7)
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at ASSERT
```

but the variable do not replace the % in the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FORMAT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
ASSERT c = 5, FORMAT('%s not 5!', c);
```